# Sending Direct Message to a user

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, slack

Right now, my bot listens to a channel in slack called 'teams' and replies in that channel. I want it to reply to the user (say 'User1') via direct message instead. How can I construct a message to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can send a Direct Message as follows:

```
    var response = await activityContext.ConnectorAPI.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(activity.Recipient, activity.From);

    var reply = activity.CreateReply($"This is a direct message to {activity.From.Name ?? activity.From.Id} : {activity.Text}");
    reply.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: response.Id);
    reply.ReplyToId = null;

    await activityContext.ConnectorAPI.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(reply);
```

Comment: Is this C#? Do you know a way to do it in Node.js? Thanks.